# Flutter "share_plus" sharePositionOrigin PlatformException on iOS

Tags: flutter, share-plus

I am using the "share_plus" Flutter library to share a file with a Firebase dynamic link. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
  ...............

  final dynamicLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(dynamicLinkParams);

  var description = 'Check this out on our app ${dynamicLink.shortUrl}';

  Share.shareXFiles([XFile(fileName)], text: description).then((value) async {
    setState(() {
      shareCount += 1;
    });

    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.remove("sharedPostId");

    Navigator.pop(context);
  });

  .................
```

On Android, the share bottom sheet opens fine. However, on iOS, the share bottom sheet does not open, and the logs display the following error message:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, sharePositionOrigin: argument must be set, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} must be non-zero and within coordinate space of source view: {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelShare.shareFilesWithResult (package:share_plus_platform_interface/method_channel/method_channel_share.dart:134)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

See the instructions for iPad on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) : the parameter `sharePositionOrigin` is required.